# lookup table in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char

I'm creating a lookup table in C
When I define this:

```
typedef struct {
 char* action;
 char* message;
} lookuptab;

lookuptab tab[] = {
  {"aa","bb"},
  {"cc","dd"}
};
```

it compiles without errors but when I do something like this:

```
typedef struct {
 char* action;
 char* message[];
} lookuptab;

lookuptab tab[] = {
  {"aaa", {"bbbb", "ccc"}},
  {"cc", {"dd", "eeeee"}}
};
```

I get the following error:

> error: initialization of flexible
>   array member in a nested context
>
> error: (near initialization for
>   ‘tab[0].message’)

How can I initialize the tab array in the second example? 
Note: I know all the values inside the tab array.

UPDATE: message could be of different size, e.g

```
typedef struct {
 char* action;
 char* message[];
} lookuptab;

lookuptab tab[] = {
  {"aaa", {"bbbb", "ccc", "dd"}},
  {"cc", {"dd", "eeeee"}}
};
```

Thank you very much.

Best regards,
Victor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use structures containing a flexible array member in an array (of the structure).  See C99 standard §6.7.2.1/2:

> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence,
>   a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance
>   of itself), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
>   may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly
>   recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an
>   element of an array.

So, use a `char **` instead (and worry about how you know how many entries there are):

```
typedef struct
{
    const char         *action;
    const char * const *message;
} lookuptab;

static const lookuptab tab[] =
{
    { "aaa", (const char * const []){ "bbbb", "ccc"   } },
    { "cc",  (const char * const []){ "dd",   "eeeee" } }
};
```

This uses a C99 construct (§6.5.2.5 Compound literals) - beware if you are not using a C99 compiler.

Comment: I'll just unpack my old C book to understand this construct ;) (Java is killing my engineering skills...)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to specify the array size to use the struct in another array:

```
typedef struct {
 char* action;
 char* message[2];
} lookuptab;
```

Comment: Either that, or just swallow the bitter pill and do the initialization using more than one line of code ;)

Comment: Hi bde, thanks, your option works, but message could also be of different size, I just updated my question to reflect that. Sorry.

Comment: BTW, using fix-max-size for message doesn't like me that much, neither.

Comment: @Victor: In that case you would have to set the size of `message` to the largest possible size. Or just manage the memory by hand using pointers, as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
 char* action;
 char* message[];
} lookuptab;
```

`lookuptab` is an incomplete type. You cannot create objects of that type. Either provide a definite size for the message array

```
typedef struct {
 char* action;
 char* message[42];
} lookuptab_definite_size;
```

or use pointers all around and manage memory "by hand"

```
typedef struct {
 char* action;
 char** message;
} lookuptab_pointers_all_around;
```

you can use the flexible array member (all elements will have the same size), but it's a lot of work :-)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct {
  char* action;
  char* message[];
} lookuptab;

int main(void) {
  lookuptab *tab;

  tab = malloc(sizeof *tab + 42 * sizeof *tab->message);
  /* tab = malloc(elems * (sizeof *tab + 42 * sizeof *tab->message)); */
  /* tab[0] ... tab[elems-1] all have the same size */
  if (tab) {
    tab->action = NULL;
    tab->message[0] = NULL;
    tab->message[1] = NULL;
    /* ... */
    tab->message[41] = NULL;
    free(tab);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't allocate an array of flexible-array-member structs like your comment suggests - the compiler has no way of knowing where `tab[1]` should start.

Comment: In my code it says all array elements have the same size, I edit the comment to make it more visible. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a size for the `message` array member in the struct definition:

```
#define N ... // maximum number of elements in message array

typedef struct
{
  char *action;
  char *message[N]; 
} lookuptab;

lookuptab tab[] = {
  {"aa", {"bb", "cc"}},
  {"dd", {"ee", "ff"}},
  ...
};
```

In this case, N must be at least 2.

If you want each instance of the `lookuptab` struct to have a different number of elements in the `message` array, then you will have to allocate each `message` array separately, meaning you won't be able to use a static initializer:

```
typedef struct
{
  char *action;
  char **messages;
} lookuptab;

lookuptab *newEntry(const char *action, size_t numMessages, ...)
{
  lookuptab *entry = malloc(sizeof *entry);
  if (entry)
  {
    entry->action = malloc(strlen(action) + 1);
    if (entry->action)
      strcpy(entry->action, action);
    if (numMessages > 0)
    {
      entry->messages = malloc(sizeof *entry->messages * numMessages);
      if (entry->messages)
      {
        size_t i;
        va_list ap;

        va_start(ap, numMessages);

        for (i = 0; i < numMessages; i++)
        {
          char *nextMessage = va_arg(ap, char *);
          entry->messages[i] = malloc(strlen(nextMessage) + 1);
          if (entry->messages[i])
            strcpy(entry->messages[i], nextMessage);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return entry;
}

int main(void)
{
  lookuptab *tab[ENTRIES]; // for some number of ENTRIES
  tab[0] = newEntry("AA", 2, "BB", "CC");
  tab[1] = newEntry("DD", 3, "EE", "FF", "GG");
  tab[2] = newEntry("HH", 0);
  ...
}
```

Instead of passing the number of messages explicitly, you can use a sentinel:

```
  tab[0] = newEntry("AA", "BB", "CC", NULL);
```

but you'll either have to cycle through all the arguments twice (first to get the number to allocate the `messages` array, then to copy each message) or you'll have to `realloc()` your array for each message, such as:

```
size_t numMessages = 0;
...
char *nextMessage
while ((nextMessage = va_arg(ap, char *)) != NULL)
{
  char **tmp = realloc(entry->messages, sizeof *entry->messages, numMessages+1);
  if (tmp)
  {
    entry->messages = tmp;
    entry->messages[numMessages] = malloc(strlen(nextMessage) + 1);
    strcpy(entry->messages[numMessages], nextMessage);
    numMessages++;
  }
}
```