# Initialise an 3d array / array of structs using a typedef in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, c-preprocessor

A tool I use produces the following output:

```
#define VAR { {1, {2,3}},  {2, {5,1,2,3,4}},  {1, {1}} }
```

I want to use this in my program. The question is how to use it properly.

My first approach was something like this:

```
#define VAR { {1, {2,3}},  {2, {5,1,2,3,4}},  {1, {1}} }
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct vars {
    int first;
    int second[];
} vars;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
   vars allvars[] = VAR;

   printf("%i\n",allvars[0].second[0]);
   return 0;
}
```

But gcc doesn't like it:

> error: initialization of flexible array member in a nested context

My second approach was about a 3d-array:

```
#define VAR { {1, {2,3}},  {2, {5,1,2,3,4}},  {1, {1}} }
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
   int allvars[3][2][2] = VAR;       
   printf("%i\n",allvars[1][1][3]);
   return 0;
}
```

Similar reaction of the compiler:

> warning: braces around scalar initializer

Does anyone know how to deal with it? Is it even possible to use an initialiser list such as the given one or do anybody knows a nice hack to deal with this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic array and prebuilt data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016627/dynamic-array-and-prebuilt-data)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875523/lookup-table-in-c.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but the ideas behind this solutions are about using malloc, arent they? But i dont want to use a malloc. Is there any possibility to avoid this? "no" is also an acceptable answer! :D

Comment: You can't do what you are trying. The posts I linked to in my earlier comments are more proof that you can't do it.